# How to register a run on Google Fit via Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-fit-api

I would like to know how to record a running workout on Google Fit via Flutter. More specifically, a treadmill workout. How do I do that? I tried to read the Google Fit API documentation, but I couldn't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at the following, to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter Fit_kit Library.

to import this into.ymal

```
dependencies:
  fit_kit: ^1.1.2
```

here the example to get HRV values

```
import 'package:fit_kit/fit_kit.dart';

class HRVStreamerAPP {
  readHRVOnce() async {
    final results = await FitKit.read(
      DataType.HEART_RATE,
      dateFrom: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3)),
      dateTo: DateTime.now(),
    );

   
    results.forEach((element) {
      print(element.toString());
    });
   
    return results;
  }

}
```

You can change the data type based on your requirements.

For example, you need steps count

```
DataType.STEP_COUNT
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want to register a workout and not read. You know how?